# How to calculate x and y axis using margin values , height and width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, crop

In my code I am cropping an image using a plugin and I need to crop the image using the coordinates in Java. But in Java I am using `image.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);` for that I need x and y axis.

```
function showPreview(coords){
   var rx = 100 / coords.w;
   var ry = 100 / coords.h;
   jQuery('#preview').css({
       width: Math.round(rx * 300) + 'px',
       height: Math.round(ry * 300) + 'px',
       marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
       marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
    });
    jQuery('#x').val(Math.round(rx * coords.x));
    jQuery('#y').val(Math.round(ry * coords.y));
    jQuery('#width').val(Math.round(rx * 300));
    jQuery('#height').val(Math.round(ry * 300));
}
```

The above code helps for previewing the image but it fails while cropping.

Comment: "i need x and y axis" - no, you need the x and y _coordinates_ for the lower left corner of the rectangle. Besides that, what's the problem? "while cropping it fails" - you didn't give any further information, so how do you expect us to help?

Comment: Yeah please remove the java tag :)

Comment: @thomas "while cropping it fails" this denotes that cropping is not accurate.Kindly provide me the solution to calculate x and y coordinates

Comment: "Kindly provide me the solution to calculate x and y coordinates" - do it correctly ;) Seriously, you've already calculated those coords in JavaScript so adapt that to Java. If you still have problems then post your code and show what you did - and tell us in what way it wasn't correct. "it fails" is one of the least specific descriptions ever: "Whenever I want to use my computer it fails" - what does that tell you?

Comment: @thomas i have just set margin-left and margin-top values to x and y. "do it correctly" I knw that is wrong thats y i am posting it for help.""it fails" forgive i posted by mistake.I just need to calculate x and y values by using height,width and margin values.I have tried someting but it doesnt provide the solution.

Comment: "I have tried someting" - you should _show_ that along with some values to check your calculations (input and expected output). `margin-top` indicates your y is the coordinate of the upper left corner so you might want to calculate the lower left coordinate, e.g. by subtracting it from the image's height. If you have some scaling in your code you need to take that into account as well, but again, without seeing some code along with values and a little info on the requirements (like scaling) it is very hard to help with your _concrete_ problem.